# Is correct to meet your future company mates in the middle of selection process?

Tags: interviewing, employer-relations, relationships

I am currently in the middle of a selection process. The selection has several stages, and I am one of the last ones. I have a friend who has been working on that company for 2 years.

Today the company is having a summer party at a pub and at that party friends and partners of the actual employees can attend.

My friend has invited me to attend and so my questions are:

Should I mention to my friends I'm on the selection process?

Should I tell them my actual status on the selection process?

Note that those responsible of evaluating my future interview will probably be at the party.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you already have a friend there, but this is a great opportunity to see the kind of people who work there and how you will fit in to the group.

Talk to everyone.  I would not lead off with "Hi I'm Javier and I am interviewing for a job with the company" but there is no reason not to mention it if the subject of employment comes up.  Who knows, you may get some insight into your future role and the people you will be interacting with on a daily basis.

Comment: One caveat: Ideally, you should check with HR/equivalent if it is ok to mention that you are interviewing. While usually this is no issue, in some cases the company might want to keep quiet about the hiring process (for example if they are secretly hiring a replacement for someone else). If they really want to keep it a secret that you are interviewing, that may also give you an insight into how they work...

Comment: Ok, yes I catch you. On this case seems to be a normal situation, there are 4 vacancies. Thanks anyway. Finally the party went so well and funny, I get some insight with the actual mates.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "correct", but it is far from uncommon. Many (but not all) companies do want to get a sense of how your personality will fit with the rest of the team, and will include a chance to meet some of all of the group as part of the interview process. This also gives you a chance to ask informal questions about what it's like to work for this company and as a member of this group that you might not ask during an official session.

Comment: Yes maybe correct is not the best word, may I want to express if ti's 'suitable', 'apropiate' good for me etc etc.. But I think you get the idea, thanks

Comment: Yes to all of these.

Answer (score 1):

This is an amazing opportunity to both feel out the company, your potential co-workers, start your professional network within the company, and make a great impression on the decision makers/hiring manager.

I would likely include the interviewing factoid in my standard introduction. "Nice to meet you. I'm Javier, I'm good friends with FRIEND, and I'm actually pursuing ROLE in DEPARTMENT." Unless someone asks more probing questions, leave it at that. Don't try to turn every conversation into an attempt to sell yourself to the company.

Be super positive with everyone.

Absolutely go, however, be aware that this is also a great opportunity lose the job.

Don't get drunk. Don't be vulgar or offensive. Be respectful of everyone, including non-employees like waitstaff, caterers, etc.

Good luck! Have fun!